# In Django how to add login required for entire app?

Tags: django, django-login

Suppose I have 3 apps in my Django website app_1, app_2, app_3. app_1 and app_2 can access any user, but for app_3 I want the user should log in.

Using `login_required` I can achieve this. But I have more than 30 views and urls. I don't want to write `login_required` decorator on every view function. Is there any other shortcut?

Comment: You can do this by introducing a middleware in your project. You will get an idea from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214589/django-how-can-i-apply-the-login-required-decorator-to-my-entire-site-excludin

Answer (score 0):

There is a [pypi](https://pypi.org/) package called [django-login-required-middelware](https://pypi.org/project/django-login-required-middleware/) for this purpose.

Just install it by:

```
pip install django-login-required-middleware
```

Then add `login_required.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware` to MIDDLEWARE in `settinggs.py` after `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware`

Comment: How can I mention that only a particular app required login?

Comment: There are options such as ignore views, paths and more. Just refer the doc